# Gradle incorrectly resolving dependency artifactId

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

I have a dependency that looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    apt 'io.sweers.barber:barber-compiler:1.3.0'
    compile 'io.sweers.barber:barber-api:1.3.0'
}
```

This dependency does exist in both jcenter and mavenCentral, but whenever gradle resolves it, it uses the incorrect artifactId (dropping the "barber-" prefix).

```
Error:Could not find io.sweers.barber:api:1.3.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/sweers/barber/api/1.3.0/api-1.3.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/sweers/barber/api/1.3.0/api-1.3.0.jar
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/sweers/barber/api/1.3.0/api-1.3.0.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/sweers/barber/api/1.3.0/api-1.3.0.jar
    file:/Users/hsweers/dev/android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/io/sweers/barber/api/1.3.0/api-1.3.0.pom
    file:/Users/hsweers/dev/android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/io/sweers/barber/api/1.3.0/api-1.3.0.jar
    file:/Users/hsweers/dev/android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/io/sweers/barber/api/1.3.0/api-1.3.0.pom
    file:/Users/hsweers/dev/android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/io/sweers/barber/api/1.3.0/api-1.3.0.jar
Required by:
    MyAppProject.app:unspecified > io.sweers.barber:barber-compiler:1.3.0
```

If the dependency would resolve correctly to `https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/sweers/barber/barber-api/1.3.0/barber-api-1.3.0.pom`

If it helps, the library can be found here: https://github.com/hzsweers/barber

Comment: If I remove `apt 'io.sweers.barber:barber-compiler:1.3.0'` from `dependencies`, Gradle seems to find the dependency, or at least processes the `build.gradle` file without issue. With that line in there, it breaks with the error that you show in your question. Not sure what that means, but perhaps it's a useful clue for you.

Comment: Yeah I think I've narrowed it down a bit to be a problem with the library releases itself. It replaces the generated POM in the compiler module with a custom one that has necessary info for mavencentral. Thing is, the resulting POM specifies the wrong artifactId. Going to dig some more

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is somewhere in my library and causing the generated pom for the compiler module to use the api module name rather than its artifactId. Hotfixed it for now